# Adding values from separate sql statement to json file, or create new JSON to update

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm currently running a php script that does a sql select/insert and creates an array from the select that is used to store those values in a JSON file at the end of the script. This works as planned.

However, I've just added a new sql statement to update a field AFTER the insert is complete, and I need to find a way to insert the updated value into the JSON file as well. I don't know how to do this, or if I can do it in the same while loop that writes to JSON, I'm afraid it would need new code but I don't know how that can write to or update the same JSON file.

Currently, the while loop that writes to that JSON file is taking every element from my select statement `$data` as `$d` and storing it in an array. HOwever, my new update statement is `$stmt2` and I have no array for that, since the value is in the same table being affected by the select/insert.

Here is the existing select/insert queries:

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                          , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                          , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Inbound
                          , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                          , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound
                            SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound
                            SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls
                          , NOW() AS Time_of_report
                          , curdate() AS Date_of_report
                      FROM cdrdb.session a
                      INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                           ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                      INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
                           ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                      WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
                      group by c.extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone 
                    (Extension,Total_Talk_Time_seconds, 
                    Total_Talk_Time_minutes, Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
                    Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Date_of_report,Time_of_report )
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                ON duplicate key update
                         Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
                         Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
                         Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
                         Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
                         Missed_Calls = values(Missed_Calls),
                         Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
                         Time_of_report = NOW()
                         ") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

And here is the while loop that writes the selected data to JSON:

```
 $content = [];

 while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iidiiiiss", $d['extension'],
          $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
          $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
          $d['Time_of_report'], $d['Date_of_report']) ;
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

     // Store the current row
     $content[] = $d;

 }

 // Store it all
 file_put_contents('ambitionLog.json', json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Lastly, here's the newly added update statement:

```
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "UPDATE jfi.ambitionphone a, 
   (SELECT * FROM jackson_id.users where id in 
   (48,75,76,77,81,82,83,85,86,87,99341,99344,99409,99422,99428)) j 
   SET a.ExtID = j.id where a.extension = j.extension") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

All I need to do is modify this somehow so that the value in `$stmt2` for `ExtID` is written into the ambitionLog.json file along with the other elements from the select statement that are already in the while loop. Everything else stays the same, I just need to know how to get this value into the JSON file.

Comment: does this query in stmt2 actually work? looks crazy. editing a json-file post-creation could be hard (possibly with jq), pre-creation would be wiser, I mean, you have the original data. just run the query for `$data` again after you have all changes done and write the results to your json file.

Comment: As an alternative, would it be possible for me to, instead of creating the json file from this array, just export my table (jfi.ambitionphone) to JSON and specify the date of records? I just have no experience with JSON, and very little with writing out files from a php script. But that would be easier if possible so I can just say ```Export jfi.ambitionphone to JSON (#name of file) where date = ''```

Comment: afaik you can't directly export json from mysql. csv is possible though. beware however, that an export query is run on the database server which might not be the server, where your php script runs on.